# Run tests in parallel using @Dataprovider

Tags: java, selenium, testng, testng-dataprovider

I want to run login test for 10 users. The user credentials are saved in an excel sheet. So, instead of running this test row after row, I want to run 3 in one go, means top 3 rows will have 3 dedicated chrome browsers launched, and then 3 more and then only 1.

[image]

**But issue is**, browsers picking data from different rows also.

[image]

**To overcome this issue** I tried using `synchronized` keyword in Test Method but then browsers are not opening in parallel, they open sequentially, execute test and quit.

How can I fix this issue? I want one dedicated chrome browser for each row.

```
public class DemoParallelTesting{

WebDriver wdriver;

@BeforeMethod
public synchronized void parallelDemo() throws Exception {
//  public void parallelDemo() throws Exception {
    wdriver = new ChromeDriver();
    wdriver.get("https://www.baseURL.com");
}

@Test(dataProvider = "loginData")
public void Registration_data(String testcasename, String sUserName, String sPassword) throws Exception {
    
    // Do login 
}

@DataProvider(name = "loginData", parallel = true)
public Object[][] getData() {
    String filepath= System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/test/resources/testData/" + "loginData.xlsx";
    Object data[][] = testData(filepath, "Sheet1");
    return data;

}

public Object[][] testData(String filepath, String sheetName) {
    // read excel file
    return data;

}
```

**testng.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" data-provider-thread-count="3">
  <test name="DemoTest" parallel="methods">
    <classes>
      <class name="rough.DemoParallelTesting"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: have you tried declaring and initializing a local `WebDriver` object inside the test?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of picking up from the excel, use data provider class to do this test. Here, you need to change:

1. Add Data provider class in the Registration_data definition

```
@Test(dataProvider = "loginData", dataProviderClass = DataProviderSource.class)
    public void Registration_data(String testcasename, String sUserName, String sPassword) throws Exception {
          
            // Do login 
    }
```

2. Create method as below in dataprovider class:

```
@DataProvider(parallel = true)
       public static Object[][] loginData() {
                Object[][] param = new Object[10][2];
                param[0][0] = test_user1;
                param[0][1] = passUser1;
                
                param[1][0] = test_user2;
                param[1][1] = passUser2;
                
                param[2][0] = test_user3;
                param[2][1] = passUser3;
        }
```

Comment: For small data I also thought of it. But if data set increases to 500 or 5000? I understand you would suggest API automation, but client is insisting to do it as UI automation. I also I want to understand threading concept. How to maintain multiple threads in parallel with no data leakage/sharing from 1 thread to another?

Comment: Can you elaborate more about the problem. When you say " browsers picking data from different rows also." i would understand there is problem with your login in testData method that is reading file from excel.

Comment: Yeah! So you see how different rows have different unique data. Now, expectation is Thread1(Browser1) should pick data from Row1, browser2 from row2 and so on. But in actual browser1 getting data fetched from other rows.